# query for pfobjects with pffile properties fails to return values with parse.com

Tags: ios, nsarray, parse-platform

I am doing a query based on the contents of an nsarray like this:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    NSArray *friends = [self.user objectForKey:@"friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"userMessage" containedIn:friends];

    [query findObjectsInBackground];
```

The Message `PFobjects` have an PFFile (image) for each Message.  The query does not return any Messages with `PFFile` images.  If a message does not have a `PFFile` associated with it, the query returns the Message with no problems.

Why am I not able to receive results for my query for those messages with `PFFiles` associated with them?

**Edit:**
I tried to not use a "containedIn" query and I was able to return results with this:

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:AWAY_MESSAGE];
    [query whereKey:@"userMessage" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

This doesn't solve my problem of getting all of the Messages for a user's friends, but it does show there is a bug with the using the containedIn query.

Is this in fact a bug, or is there a problem with my first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the files I was querying had ACLs on them.